# Touchpad multi-tap buttons not configured correctly on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer C7 chromebook with chrubuntu. Overall, it works very well, but there is one minor problem. I would like one finger for left click, and two for right click.

I can achieve this easily with the following commands

```
synclient TapButton1=1
synclient TapButton2=3
synclient TapButton3=2
```

However, after reboot (or closing/opening the lid), when I query synclient, the settings are as follows:

```
TapButton1 = 3
TapButton2 = 1
TapButton3 = 0
```

This is an odd and undesirable three-finger left click! This persists, even though I have added the following lines to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf

```
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "3"
Option "TapButton3" "2"
```

I've tried adding the synclient commands to correctly configure the touchpad to /etc/rc.local, but it still starts up incorrectly. The only workaround is a script that sets up the touchpad correctly, which I run everytime I re-open the lid. It works, but not the most elegant fix for an otherwise excellent system

Any idea how I can make the touchpad configured correctly at startup, or re-opening the lid?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing following two packages could solve your issue:

```
xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Follow these steps to remove completely and install it again.

- Open terminal and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
  ```

  be sure you don't remove any other package than `xserver-xorg-input-multitouch`

  ```
  sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
  ```

  again follow the same precaution.
- Once removed execute these commands to install it again:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
  ```

  again be sure you don't remove any other packages while installing it.
- Once installed execute following commands to `reconfigure` it:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```
- Then restart your system. Reply if you need further assistance..

**Edit**

If above method doesn't help then you can give a try to [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings) [image: Install gpointing-device-settings].

- You can install it by command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gsynaptics
  ```
- When installed open it by searching `gsynaptics` or `pointing devices` in dash. You can also open it by browsing the path `/usr/share/applications` through any file manager. Hope its configuration helps you.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried this, but there doesn't seem to be any change. When I start up, I've still got the odd mouse configuration. Any other ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention a link. Have you tried [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

Comment: Also try to install `gsynaptics`! Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it. The mouse was set up as "left handed" under mouse settings, not sure why. This should be a bug as the left/right handed mouse settings should not affect touchpad tapping.